# How do I add a group in Mac OS X 10.6?

Tags: mac-osx, groups

Surprisingly, it's been tough for me to find the command(s) to do this.  Does anyone know how to add a group?  Thanks!

Or do something like this:

```
# create the MySQL group
dscl . create /Groups/mysql
# give it some group id
dscl . create /Groups/mysql gid 296
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've used these to add dba group:

```
sudo dscl . -create /groups/dba
sudo dscl . -append /groups/dba gid 4200
sudo dscl . -append /groups/dba passwd "*"
```

Comment: Not sure if things have changed since this answer was written, but with El Capitan (v10.11), in order to get the group name to display in `ls -l` commands, I had to use a variation of the second command, `sudo dscl . -append /groups/dba PrimaryGroupID 4200`

I got the field name from the output of `sudo dscl . -readall /groups`.

Comment: ...and `passwd` is now `Password`.

Answer (score 33):

"System preferences" -> "Users&Groups" -> "+" (as if you were adding new account) -> Under "New account" select "Group" -> Type in group name -> "Create group"

Answer (score 14):

pulegium's answer is generally preferred, but if you want a command-line way:

```
sudo dseditgroup -o create mysql
```

(note that creating a group named mysql is probably a bad idea -- there's already a group named _mysql, with mysql as an alias.)

Comment: "pulegium's answer" is apparently no longer available.  Do you remember what it was?

Comment: IIRC it was to use System Preferences -- a lot like rytis' answer.  (@rytis: did you change your username, by any chance?)

Comment: In my opinion, this is the most stable answer for creating a group on Mac OSX.  In testing a solution for my latest product ([xcron](https://github.com/cubiclesoft/xcron)), I found that `dseditgroup` appears to produce the most consistent results a decade later while `dscl` has undergone inconsistent changes over the same time period.

Answer (score 8):

As Gordon Davisson notes, standard Mac OS X 10.6 already has a mysql group, as this command shows:

```
dscl . -read /Groups/mysql
```

You shouldn’t create your own mysql group, and any attempts to modify it will affect the _mysql group.  But to answer your question, the most succinct way to do it would be this single command:

```
dscl . -create /Groups/mysql gid 296
```

To add an encrypted password to the group:

```
dscl . -passwd /Users/mysql ‘my secret’
```

Note:  Andrea Girardi’s method creates a plaintext password, which isn’t so good.